# Deriving maximum horizontal distance between two graphs

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Apologies if this question is actually obvious - I'm trying to derive a given result in a textbook, [Analog to Digital Conversion](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-44971-5) by Pelgrom. It's an engineering text but my question is about the mathematical derivation of the maximum horizontal distance between two graphs as shown in the first figure below. (This is the so-called "integral nonlinearity".)

The setup is: There is one real-valued function in green, $y_1=V_{in}$ defined for $V_{in}$ in the range of 0 to a constant, positive real number $V_{ref}$. There is a another function in red which is a nonlinear approximation to $y_1$, defined as:

$$y_2=V_{in}(1+\alpha(V_{ref}-V_{in}))$$

So $y_2$ coincides with $y_1$ at the origin and at $V_{in}=V_{ref}$ but has a quadratic bow between those points. As shown in the figure the maximum *horizontal* distance between the graphs, is equal to $\alpha V_{ref}^2/4$. This is the result I want to derive.

What I'm uncertain about is that the quantity I want to find the maximum of is defined along between points on the functions' inputs, not the outputs. My first attempts were to try to re-formulate the problem in terms of $y_2$'s inverse, but that was becoming a bit of a mess. So instead I wanted to see what would happen if instead I just calculated the maximum of the difference between $y_2$, $y_1$ (so along the vertical axis), and this gave me the same result of $\alpha V_{ref}^2/4$. But I'm not sure how to justify that this is then equal to the maximum horizontal distance, or maybe it might be a coincidence? If it's not, then under what conditions would this approach work? For example, would the same procedure be valid for the case of a cubic function as shown in the bottommost figure?

[image: Two curves]

[image: Cubic]

Comment: Well, I can't say much about the specific functions in the OP, but given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we need to find $h(x) = |f^{-1}(x) - g^{-1} (x)|$. Where $\frac{d h(x)}{dx} = 0$, we have the maximum horizontal distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

We have for $\{y_1,y_2\}\in [0, V_r]$

$$
\cases{
y_1 = V\\
y_2 = V(1+\alpha(V_r- V))
}
$$

so we need to solve

$$
y^* = \arg\max{\left(y-\frac{\alpha V_r+1\pm\sqrt{(\alpha V_r+1)^2-4\alpha y}}{2\alpha}\right)^2}=\arg\max{\|y-\frac{\alpha V_r+1\pm\sqrt{(\alpha V_r+1)^2-4\alpha y}}{2\alpha}\|}\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ 0 < y < V_r
$$

NOTE

Considering instead

$$
y^* = \arg\max{\left(y-\frac{\alpha V_r+1+\sigma\sqrt{(\alpha V_r+1)^2-4\alpha y}}{2\alpha}\right)^2}\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ 0 < y < V_r
$$

we have null derivative at

$$
\cases{
y^*=\frac{(\alpha V_r+1)^2-\sigma^2}{4 \alpha}\\
y^*= -\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2 \left(a^2 V_r^2+\sigma ^2-1\right)}-\alpha V_r+\sigma ^2-1}{2 \alpha}\\
y^*=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma ^2 \left(\alpha^2 V_r^2+\sigma ^2-1\right)}+\alpha V_r-\sigma ^2+1}{2 \alpha}
}
$$

or as $\sigma^2=1$ at

$$
\cases{
y^*= \frac{(\alpha V_r+1)^2-1}{4 \alpha}\\
y^*= 0\\
y^*= V_r
}
$$